# Xamarin Forms Button pressed event for 3 seconds executes action or nothing

Tags: forms, xamarin, button, pressed

I need to write a event behind a button, when i pressed it for 3 seconds a method must executes. If i released it before the 3 seconds, it doesnt do anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Xamarin Forms 2.4, buttons have included `Pressed` and `Released` events.

Start a 3 second timer in the `Pressed` event. Cancel it in the `Released` event if it hasn't fired.